# How to check if an element exists more than once in matrix (C)?

Tags: c, matrix

I'm studying C programming language, and I came across a question that I got stuck trying to solve. I tried searching for an answer to my question, but I couldn't find.

My question is how to check if an element exists more than once in a matrix. Also, if it exists more than once but in the same row, it doesn't count.

I tried writing a function to do this, but when I look at it I get a headache hehe, so I guess I did it all wrong from the start.

Can someone please tell me how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lets see the function. You'll find in short-order where you went wrong and  why. When posting it, include a description of what it appears to be doing vs. what you were expecting it to do.

Comment: Do you want to output numbers that are repeated in the matrix but in some other row?

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried? What you need is to iterate over each element of the matrix, and compare it against all the other elements.

Comment: @Dan: Can you please perhaps post the function here?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if an element exists more than once in an matrix: Sort the whole array (as if it would be a single linear vector). Then go linear through the vector and check if neighbouring elements are the same.
2. Check if an element exists more than once in a column of a matrix: Do the same as in 1. but only for each column.

Answer (score 0):

For what you ask, you need to analyze all the element in the matrix. You also need to keep track if the element was already found in that column. Here is a sample code:

```
int count(int **matrix, int rows, int cols, int number) {
  int count=0, found_in_row=0, i, j;
  for(i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<cols; j++) {
      if(matrix[i][j]==number && found_in_row==0) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    found_in_row=0;
  }
 return count;
}
```

Now suppose i have this matrix:

```
1 2 1
1 2 3
```

By calling `count(matrix, 3, 3, 1)` you will get 2 as answer. That mean that the number 1 occur two times (withount counting the second 1 on the first row).
So, by calling `count` on you matrix you will know if `number` occur more than once by checking if is greater than 1.

Comment: That was helpful, but what I meant is to check if an element **inside** the matrix exists more than once. So the function needs to check every element in the matrix if it appears again, but in a different row.

Comment: i have edited my answer adding an example. If this is not you asked, please give me more datails on what you want

Comment: You are sending a number on function call. What I meant, is that the function has to check if a number from inside the matrix itself repeats itself. The function doesn't receive a number and check if it exists more than once in the matrix, it checks if a number in the matrix itself appears again in the matrix.